# Windows folder contents inside other folder without moving them?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Using Windows 7.

I have a folder on c: and I want to store some of the contents of this folder on d:.

The problem is I have software that needs to see the full contents in the c: folder and the software only has space to enter one folder as the location to look (so I can't just enter both folder locations).

Question: How can I move some files from the c: folder into a d: folder while making it look like the c: folder contains all the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what you use [file junctions or symbolic links](http://ipggi.wordpress.com/2009/09/07/windows-file-junctions-symbolic-links-and-hard-links/) for.

These are a bit confusing initially and they [have been discussed extensively on superuser](https://www.google.com/search?q=file+junctions+symbolic+links+site%3Asuperuser.com)

It's a bit much to fully quote here, the first link tells you how to map to directories to each other using the [mklink] command:

mklink /D [LINK NAME] [TARGET]

creates a directory symbolic link which is a pointer to a directory.

There's no file moving or copyimng involved.

Comment: It looks complicated but is also exactly what I need...  thanks!  Is it possible to use mklink using just the windows GUI?